# NSURLConnection Delegate Methods won't be called...can't figure it out and read a lot of posts

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I've got a class called `BackendConnector` which uses a `NSURLConnection` to call a `SoapWebservice` that is https. I found a lot of posts and tried to implement the delegate Methods regarding Authentication but they won't get called and after 6 hours in google I don't get what I've done wrong. Can someone please give me a hint why those 2 Delegate Methods won't get called? I set a breakpoint in each one, started my app with XCode in the simulator but still get the error and the Breakpoints don't get hit.

```
BackendConnector.m

#import "BackendConnector.h"

@implementation BackendConnector

@synthesize dataPoint, chartDataPoints;

- (NSMutableArray *)GetWebserviceData
{
    NSMutableData *myMutableData;
    chartDataPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self createWebserviceAndGetResponse: &myMutableData];

    if (myMutableData != NULL)
    {
        NSString *theXml = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[myMutableData mutableBytes] length:[myMutableData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"doc = %@", theXml);

        arrayCount = 0;
        [self parseResponse: myMutableData];
    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                        message:@"There is no Data returned from Webservice!"
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}

    return NULL;
    //return chartDataPoints;
}

- (void) createWebserviceAndGetResponse: (NSMutableData **) myMutableData_p  
{
    NSMutableString *sRequest = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    [sRequest appendString:@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ser=\"http://service.ReportWebservice.xyz.com/\">"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<soapenv:Header/>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<soapenv:Body>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<ser:getReport>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<arg0>User/arg0>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"<arg1>password</arg1>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"</ser:getReport>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"</soapenv:Body>"];
    [sRequest appendString:@"</soapenv:Envelope>"];

    NSURL *myWebserverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xyz.com/services/report"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myWebserverURL]; 
    NSLog(@"request: %@", request);

    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

    NSString *contentLengthStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sRequest length]];

    [request addValue:contentLengthStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[sRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn)
    {
        *myMutableData_p=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSError *WSerror;
    NSURLResponse *WSresponse;

    *myMutableData_p = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&WSresponse error:&WSerror];
}

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
@end
```

The Error is:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “xyz.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0x8161600 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xyz.com/services/report, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xyz.com/services/report, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “xyz.com” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSUnderlyingError=0x8134cb0 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “xyz.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.", NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x6d86020>}
```

Thank you very much

twickl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't be able to answer why those methods aren't getting fired, I have the exact same methods and they get called when using HTTPS, but I'm wondering why you aren't implementing the rest of the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods? Such as `-didReceiveResponse` etc.

I also think that your connection actually initiates at

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

You shouldn't have `[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];` and lastly you are starting and setting another synchronous NSURLConnection and storing it into what should be `NSMutableData`.

Try using only your first `NSUrlConnection *conn` (and be sure to release it properly later) and then setup your data in the `-didReceiveResponse` delegate method, and you can actually set or append the data in the `-didReceiveData` delegate method.

Comment: You're right...now it works. Use the correct and only instance and the delegate Methods get called!

Answer (score 6):

Late but it may be useful to others

Solution link is  http://www.wim.me/nsurlconnection-in-its-own-thread/

Comment: i had this exact problem and would have taken all night to figure it out